# "Global" Office 365 Apps

Tags: office-365

I know that different kinds of custom apps for Office 365 can be developed. For example, a SharePoint Add-In or an app for Excel, etc. My question is, if there is a way to create a “global” Office 365 app? With that I mean an app, which is somehow displayed to the user everywhere in the Office 365 subscription?

I also know that custom apps can be added to the App Launcher. From my understanding, this is basically a tile with a link to the specific app. And as it’s in the App Launcher, which is available everywhere, the user can quickly access this app.

But this is not really what I’m looking for. The idea is to create an app which is (or at least can be) actually installed “everywhere” – for example to provide a global, unified navigation across all products in the subscription?